# What is the cause of this NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, android-asynctask, okhttp

Before you hover over the close button. Please fully read this question.

### Preface

Obviously, this exception is caused by running a network operation on the Main Thread. However, as you can see from the stacktrace, this error originates within `doInBackground` of an `AsyncTask`! I also do not transition onto the Main Thread after that point.

Interestingly, I cannot replicate this issue on my devices. It is also not an issue that crops up for the vast majority of my users. Therefore, it cannot be a general implementation error.

### Steps

1. Main Thread
2. Something causes the channel list to refresh (be it manual or initial load)
3. My API library is called (appendix 1)
4. Background Thread
5. The `AsyncTask` calls the API library to get the body of a URL (appendix 2)
6. My Cache library checks whether the body has already been saved, it does not change the `Thread`.
7. The API library calls the necessary `OkHttp` methods to pull the body of the URL (appendix 3)

### Stacktrace

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
       at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
       at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:249)
       at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:549)
       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:481)
       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:237)
       at okio.Okio$2.read(SourceFile:139)
       at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(SourceFile:211)
       at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(SourceFile:306)
       at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(SourceFile:300)
       at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(SourceFile:196)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponse(SourceFile:184)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponseHeaders(SourceFile:125)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(SourceFile:723)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.access$200(SourceFile:81)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine$NetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(SourceFile:708)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(SourceFile:563)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(SourceFile:241)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(SourceFile:198)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(SourceFile:160)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(SourceFile:57)
       at com.mypackagename.app.http.Api.getBody(SourceFile:1472)
       at com.mypackagename.app.tasks.GetChannelListTask$2.renewCache(SourceFile:72)
       at com.mypackagename.app.utils.Cache.get(SourceFile:27)
       at com.mypackagename.app.tasks.GetChannelListTask.doInBackground(SourceFile:69)
       at com.mypackagename.app.tasks.GetChannelListTask.doInBackground(SourceFile:24)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

### Appendix 1

```
public void getChannelList(final IGetChannelListCallback callback) {
    try {
        GetChannelListTask task = new GetChannelListTask(mContext.get(), callback);
        AsyncTaskCompat.executeParallel(task);
    } catch (RejectedExecutionException e) {
        Crashlytics.logException(e);
    }
}
```

### Appendix 2

```
protected ArrayList<Channel> doInBackground(String... urls) {
    final ArrayList<Channel> channelList = new ArrayList<Channel>();

    // ...

    String json = Cache.get(context, GET_CHANNELS_CACHE, GET_CHANNELS_CACHE_TIME, new IBadCache() {
        public String renewCache() {
            return Api.getInstance(context).getBody(GET_CHANNELS_URL);
        }
    });

    // ...

    return channelList;
}
```

### Appendix 3

```
@WorkerThread
@NonNull
public String getBody(@NonNull final String url) {
    try {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(logUrl(url))
                .build();

        Response response = mClient.newCall(request).execute();

        return response.body().string();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Utils.log("API", "E::"+e.toString());
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        reportNoInternetPermission();
    }

    return "";
}
```

### Update 1

Checking the Thread resulted in the expected:

```
refreshChannelList: MainThread: true
getChannelList: MainThread: true
onPreExecute: MainThread: true
doInBackground: MainThread: false
renewCache: MainThread: false
getBody: MainThread: false
onPostExecute: MainThread: true
```

Moving to a background Thread upon `doInBackground` and continuing through to the `OkHttp` call, returning to the Main Thread once at `onPostExecute`.

Comment: Can you put some logging statements to find out what code is run on which thread? For example at the start and end of `doInBackground`, the cache callback, `getBody`, etc. You can use `Thread.currentThread()` for that.

Comment: is getChannelList is called from inside an activity?

Comment: not sure but is this  line getBody(..) -> `mClient.newCall(request).execute()` cause..  reason : executing on worker thread instead of main thread.

Comment: @nhaarman: Updated question. Expected result. OmriErEz: it is called from a `Fragment`. Specifically in `onResume` and within a `Handler` created on the Main Thread. skadoosh: That is the part of my code that leads to OkHttp. This part is absolutely running on a Background thread, not the Main thread. (it runs in `doInBackground` but I also just ran a test to make sure)

Answer (score 0):

Hm, looks like your problem in in case when your do something(calling some operation with context usage), in doInbackground method. If your context instance of Activity/Fragment etc. (taking from UI component) thats mean that operation which used your context use MainThread for executing. thats why u can get such kind of exception. 
Try execute this

```
String json = Cache.get(context, GET_CHANNELS_CACHE, GET_CHANNELS_CACHE_TIME, new IBadCache() {
    public String renewCache() {
        return Api.getInstance(context).getBody(GET_CHANNELS_URL);
    }
});
```

on

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... values) {
  super.onProgressUpdate(values);

}
```

with publishProgress(Object obj); on doInbackground method. It must help

Comment: `Context` doesn't infer which Thread the code is running in. Changing what `Context` is passed into the caching method (or `Api`) will not affect it. Why do you suggest running the code in `onProgressUpdate`? That will guarantee that the caching method will run on the Main Thread, which is the opposite of what I need at that point.

Comment: Ok, sorry for missunderstanding. If you want use context depends operation in highload execution i can see 2 solutions. First one is IntentService(other thread). Another is AIDL(other process). Do you know about it or description needs?

Comment: I could move the API to services, but that really would be overkill right now. That also doesn't resolve the underlying issue. I shouldn't need to explore additional types of framework, since the `AsyncTask` should be handling the background thread.

Comment: What do you mean under "additional types of framework"?

Comment: I mean that `AsyncTask` should work fine for the purpose of a simple HTTP call. Instead of using more heavy frameworks like `IntentService` or `AIDL`. It would be better for me to locate the underlying bug.

Comment: May be AIDL is hard to understand, but most of the high loaded Android services use it, especially for a lot of data transaction(IO, Networking etc). You can format your code to function block and play with entities instead of overhead code writing.